# RxSwift, binding Action to UIButton stops producing events after view transitions

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, action, rx-swift

I'm trying to implement a MVVM login screen using RxSwift and encountered some difficulties.

My login screen (user, password, login button) transitions to a camera view screen, where the app checks for camera permissions, and if those are not approved, logs the user out and returns to the login screen.

I have a `loginAction` in my `LoginViewModel` that returns an `Action<Void, LoginResult>`, where `LoginResult` is a [`Result<Bool, Error>`](https://github.com/antitypical/Result) and my `loginProvider` service returns an `Observable<LoginResult>`:

```
struct LoginViewModel {

let sceneCoordinator: SceneCoordinatorType
let loginProvider: LoginProviderType

var usernameText = Variable<String>("")
var passwordText = Variable<String>("")

var isValid: Observable<Bool> {
    return Observable.combineLatest(usernameText.asObservable(), passwordText.asObservable()) { username, password in
        username.count > 0 && password.count > 0
    }
}

init(loginProvider: LoginProvider, coordinator: SceneCoordinatorType) {
    self.loginProvider = loginProvider
    self.sceneCoordinator = coordinator
}

lazy var loginAction: Action<Void, LoginResult> = { (coordinator: SceneCoordinatorType, service: LoginProviderType, username: String, password: String) in
    return Action<Void, LoginResult>(enabledIf: self.isValid) { _ in
        return service.login(username: username, password: password)
            .observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
            .do(onNext: { result in
                guard let loggedIn = result.value else { return }
                if loggedIn {
                    let cameraViewModel = CameraViewModel(coordinator: coordinator)
                    coordinator.transition(to: Scene.camera(cameraViewModel), type: .modal)
    }
}(self.sceneCoordinator, self.loginProvider, self.companyText.value, self.usernameText.value, self.passwordText.value)
}
```

Everything works fine, valid input logs in successfully (`loginProvider` sends the request the my server, get the response and handles all additional steps accordingly).

In case that the user doesn't grant camera permissions, I have a `Observable` for that in my `CameraViewModel` which I bind to my `CameraViewController`, subscribe to and in case needed, log the user out and pop the view back to the login screen using `CocoaAction` that pops the current view (using a scene coordinator class).

Problem is, when I try to log in again after transitioning back to the Login screen, the subscription for the elements emitted by the `loginAction` doesn't receive any elements.

Here's the code for the `LoginViewController`:

```
class LoginViewController: UIViewController, BindableType {

var viewModel: LoginViewModel!

private let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

private var loginAction: Action<Void, LoginResult>!

@IBOutlet weak var usernameTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var loginButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var loadingIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!


private var usernameObservable: Observable<String> {
    return usernameTextField.rx.text
        .throttle(0.5, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
        .map() { text in
            return text ?? ""
    }
}

private var passwordObservable: Observable<String> {
    return passwordTextField.rx.text
        .throttle(0.5, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
        .map() { text in
            return text ?? ""
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

func bindViewModel() {

    usernameObservable
        .bind(to: viewModel.usernameText)
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)

    passwordObservable
        .debug()
        .bind(to: viewModel.passwordText)
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)

    loginAction = viewModel.loginAction

    loginAction.elements
        .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] result in
            self?.loadingIndicator.stopAnimating()
            var message = ""
            switch result {
            case  .failure(.unknownError):
                message = "unknown error"
            case .failure(.wrongCredentials):
                message = "wrong credentials"
            case .failure(.serviceUnavailable):
                message = "service unavailable"
            case let .success(loggedIn):
                return
            }
            self?.errorMessage(message: message)
    }).disposed(by: disposeBag)

    loginButton.rx.tap
        .subscribe(onNext: { [unowned self] in
                self.loadingIndicator.startAnimating()
                self.loginAction.execute(Void())
            })
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)

    viewModel.isValid
        .bind(to: loginButton.rx.isEnabled)
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
}
```

I can see that tapping the login button produces the tap event, however the Action itself stops being called. Any idea what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue: Apparently the action didn't reach a complete state because one on the underlying services returned an observer that was subscribed in the login view controller and not disposed when returning to it from the camera view controller.

I've added a clearing method in that service which creates a new `DisposeBag` when returning to the login view, which allows the action to complete and released for reuse.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how ScreenCoordinator works, but I would start with moving creation of *usernameObservable/passwordObservable* to *viewDidLoad()* because the issue seems to be lifecycle-related. Also, you can add a few more *.debug()* calls (with parameter to be able to distinguish between them in the logs).

Comment: SceneCooardinator is implemented very similarly to the one described [here](https://medium.com/smoke-swift-every-day/rxswift-coordinator-pattern-done-right-c8f123fdf2b2).
Basically all views are embedded in their own Navigation Controller, and transition is done from one controller to another.

As for debug calls, I'm using them in my code, removed them from the post to clear the text. Unfortunately they didn't help me find an issue.

I'll give it a try about moving my computed variables to viewDidLoad() and update accordingly.

Comment: Just tried moving my computed variables to viewDidLoad(), didn't help. The problem isn't with them, rather with the action object itself. It's being called on tap (_self.loginAction.execute(Void())_), but for some reason the code doesn't reach the actual implementation in the viewModel.